# Adding source files to Gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Let's assume I've got a simple Android project which I'm gonna build by Gradle.

Is it possible to **add** sources from arbitrary directory?

So I'd like to keep main sourceSets intact, just to add some java-files which are located in *path to sources*.

Comment: See also [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32357239/2350083)

Answer (score 3):

Just add the folder to `java.srcDir`. It is just a Set of Files, so you can add more Files like any other Set in groovy.

One example to do so is to add this snippet:

```
sourceSets {
    main{
        java {
            srcDir("path/to/source/folder")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example? Because I've tried and what I got was setting the sourceroot to that folder.

Comment: @The Thanks. Does this code relocate sourceroot or add specified folder to exiting sourceroot?

Comment: This code add the path to srcDir. So it compiles and jars both, the project source folder and the files in `"path/to/source/folder"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to finally do this. In my case I wanted to have some common java source files for a couple different build flavors.

```
sourceSets {
    favorA1 {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/favorA1/java/src', 'src/commonA/java/src')
        }
    }
    favorA2 {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/favorA2/java/src', 'src/commonA/java/src')
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want to add a source directory to all of your build variants, try something like the following:

```
sourceSets {
    main{
        java {
            srcDirs('src/main/java/src', 'src/additionalCode/java/src', '../other/sources')
        }
    }
}
```

[Gradle Java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#configureSourceSet)
[Gradle Source Api](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html)