# Android Flavors : Multiple java and src directories for each flavor

Tags: java, android, gradle, src

Can anyone explain to me how I can use for each of my flavors more then just the main and the flavor specific java/src directories ? My goal is to have directories which are used by more than one flavor but not all of them.

For example I have 3 flavors : A1, A2 and B.

- All favors use main/src (default main src directory)
- A1 uses A1/src (default flavor src directory)
- A2 uses A2/src (default flavor src directory)
- B uses B/src (default flavor src directory)
- **A1 and A2 use A/src ("special" shared directory)**

Is this possible ? If so, what should I put in my build.gradle file ?

And as a bonus question, can I chose in which order gradle goes looking for files in my different directories ?

For example if I have a.png declared in both A/src and A1/src, can I tell gradle to first look for this file in A/src, and only if nothing is found look for it in A1/src ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging)

> As mentioned above, each sourceSet can define multiple resource folders.

You can define multiple resource folder. For example something like this:

```
android {
     ...
     sourceSets {
            main {
                //....
                res.srcDirs = ['/src/main/res']

            }
            flavorA1 {
                 res.srcDirs = ['/src/flavor1/res', '/src/commonA/res']
            }
            flavorA2 {
                 res.srcDirs = ['/src/flavor2/res', '/src/commonA/res']
            }     
            //.....other flavors   
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found a slightly different format is required for setting *java* source files

```
sourceSets {
    favorA1 {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/favorA1/java/src', 'src/commonA/java/src')
        }
    }
    favorA2 {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/favorA2/java/src', 'src/commonA/java/src')
        }
    }
}
```

[Gradle Java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#configureSourceSet)
[Gradle Source Api](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html)