# Android/ Gradle: Include few files from one flavor to another flavor?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have three BuildTypes release, debug & custom. I want to keep few files from release in custom Build. buildTypes allows me to keep all the stuff from release using 'custom.initWith'. Does sourceSets have something like it?

```
buildTypes {
        release { // release stuff}
        debug { // debug stuff}
        custom.initWith(buildTypes.release)
        custom { // custom stuff }
               }
sourceSets {
        main.setRoot('src/main')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        custom.setRoot( //Want to include some files from 'build-types/release' 
                          and all files from 'build-types/custom')
```

Is this possible through Gradle in Android?

setRoot allows me to include only 'build-types/custom'. 
It's possible to have required files from 'build-types/release' folder to 'build-types/custom'. This has a disadvantage.

1. Duplicate files in release and custom folders.
2. Also If we modify something in release needs to be modified in custom.

Other question has specific needs for Resources files only. [Android Flavors : Multiple java and src directories for each flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357239/android-flavors-multiple-java-and-src-directories-for-each-flavor). I want to share files from other folder which has res, assets,java, & manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You can include resource from multiple folders through script along the line of

```
sourceSets {
    custom.manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    custom.java.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
    custom.resources.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
    custom.aidl.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
    custom.renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
    custom.assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    custom.res.srcDirs = ['src/custom/res', src/main/res']
}
```

OR put `custom` in its own block:

```
sourceSets {
    custom {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/commonFiles/java']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/custom/res', src/main/res']
    }
}
```

See also [Resource Merging](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging)

Comment: This one works only with resources files 'src/custom/res'. Do i need to include the same for java, assets & manifest?

Comment: @wangadu please see edited answer, can't say I've used all of them though